# Is "as it stands" used outside the UK?

Tags: idioms, world-english

Often used for presenting a tentative sports league table while games are still in play - "here's the league table as it stands..."

(It kind of means "now", but implying the situation could change.)

Is this usage common in international usage?

Comment: I trust you did not mean to exclude Canada and New Zealand.

Comment: @tchrist, Canada, NZ, would fall under 'elsewhere', would it not?

Comment: It's better to use Commonwealth countries in place of Australia/elsewhere.

Comment: @Rathony - Why would you exclude Ireland?

Comment: "As it stands" is reasonably idiomatic in the US.  Used in lots of contexts besides sports, though.  One might expect to hear "Here is the situation on the college shooting as it stands at the moment."

Comment: Haha. And what about India, huh huh? :-) (FWIW, this expression is used and understood here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used in the USA, and generally has a proper or elevated tone, as opposed to something like "at the moment" or "currently". I believe the elevation comes from the phrase sounding British to American ears.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, I can confirm it is used in the US, usually to mean "currently".